# Editing an XML object - IdentityProvider

Tags: xml, powershell

I am attempting to alter a value of an XML object with another value. However my reassignment is failing with an error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='

```
$webConfig.configuration.Configuration.SingleSignOnConfiguration.IdentityProviders.add |
  ? {$_.name -eq "IdentityProvider"} |
  select Name = $identityProviderName
```

Can someone correct my syntax and tell me why? Is it because the left side of the argument is not interpreted as a single value? I know my XML is fine as I use this code to pull the value I need.

Comment: `select Name = $identityProviderName` -> `%{$_.Name=$identityProviderName}` Not every `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I will research through the syntax to understand. Thanks again.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as your previous one.

Comment: I understand that now.